# jQuery error when using image slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have an image slider ([NivoSlider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)) which simply fades through a range of images on our website. It's working fine on the homepage with the following code:

**HEAD of INDEX.PHP**

```
<!-- Image Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_ui/css/slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="_ui/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices:15, // For slice animations
    boxCols: 8, // For box animations
    boxRows: 4, // For box animations
    animSpeed:500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime:2000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide:0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav:false, // Next & Prev navigation
    directionNavHide:false, // Only show on hover
    controlNav:false, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs:false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, // Use image rel for thumbs
    controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
    controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
    keyboardNav:true, // Use left & right arrows
    pauseOnHover:false, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance:false, // Force manual transitions
    captionOpacity:0.8, // Universal caption opacity
    prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
    beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
    afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
    slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
    });
    </script>
```

**DIV OF SLIDER IN INDEX.PHP**

```
    <div class="nivoSlider">
     <img src="_media/img/home_first_final.jpg" alt="" />
     <img src="_media/img/home_second_final.jpg" alt="" />
     <img src="_media/img/home_third_final.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

The above code is working fine and can be reviewed [here](http://hillcrestanimalhospital.co.uk/).

When I try and re-use the code on a sub-content page I get the following error:

```
[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'
  (anonymous function)
  c.event.handle
  c.event.add.j.handle.o
```

I checked the code on the sub-content pages (an example page [here](http://hillcrestanimalhospital.co.uk/services.php)) and the code is now an exact duplicate of the HEAD of INDEX.PHP but the DIV is as follows:

```
<div class="nivoSlider">
 <img src="_media/img/services_first_final.jpg" alt="" />
 <img src="_media/img/services_second_final.jpg" alt="" />
 <img src="_media/img/services_third_final.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: in the first case you're using `$('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider` on the second you used `$('#slider').nivoSlider`, why not use the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading jQuery twice on the second page.

You have this near the end of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_ui/js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error sis telling you that there's no "nivoSlider" method on a certain object.

Looking into your code, the object it's trying to call that method on is: $('.nivoSlider')

Is it possible that when you load your subpage that the item that has the nivoSlider class either doesn't exist - or is something that you didn't expect?

Or (FTW) that there is more than one of them... and thus it's returning an array (instead of a  single object)  and thus needs to be run using "each"

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

Check to see that any included scripts do not include the line:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This will break scripts that use the $ jQuery alias.